# Plotting in R language using ggplot

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, scale, bubble-chart

I have a list of cities and their coordinates, and also for each city I have a variable varA which I want to represent in a map using ggplot and bubble chart.
For example :

```
CityA  lat 22.93977 lon 46.70663 varA 545
CityB  lat 23.93977 lon 46.70663 varA 122
```

VarA values begin from 0 to 3000.
I want the color scale to represent  this range appropriately.
Can you help?

Comment: You mention color representing your value, in a bubble chart this is typically the size of a point and not the color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bubble chart in `ggplot2` is actually a point plot (`geom_point`), where the `size` aesthetic is assigned to a (continuous) variable. The following example shows a bubble chart as you described for the `meuse` dataset (part of the `sp` package). It shows heavy metal concentrations close to the river meuse in the Netherlands.

```
library(sp)
data(meuse)
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())

ggplot(meuse, aes(x = x, y = y, size = zinc)) + geom_point()
```

[image]